# Postfix authentication issues after I configured TLS

Tags: postfix

I've setup my mail server with Postfix for SMTP and Dovecot for IMAP. Instead of virtual users I simply listened to the suggestion of someone from Server Fault and went with Linux users. I'm using RainLoop as a webmail service. I have configured SPF and in order to have my emails reach other providers, I have to use authentication.

So I (tried to) setup TLS to work with the SSL certificate I have got by using the Let's Encrypt client. The following is my `main.cf` file:

```
# domain name and public server ip are replaced with mydomain.co.il and 127.0.0.1
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.co.il/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.co.il/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.mydomain.co.il
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
myorigin = mydomain.co.il
mydestination = mail.mydomain.co.il, localhost.mydomain.co.il, localhost, hash:/etc/postfix/transport
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.10.0/24 127.0.0.1 # last one is the server's public ip
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

And the following is my `master.cf` file:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

I basically just enabled `sumbission`.

RainLoop connects to both my IMAP server and SMTP server:

[RainLoop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O08ET.png)

As long as "Use Authentication" is disabled or if I use the php `mail();` function, I'm able to send emails and receive them everywhere. They get marked as spam, so I figured out I need to enable authentication but if I do so; I'm unable to send emails, this is from my `mail.log` file:

```
# i replaced my server's public ip address with 127.0.0.1
Jun 23 05:14:57 mailserver dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<shavit>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=16305, TLS, session=<QVtwdek15swlOzfP>
Jun 23 05:14:57 mailserver postfix/smtpd[16306]: connect from mydomain.co.il[127.0.0.1]
Jun 23 05:14:57 mailserver postfix/smtpd[16306]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mydomain.co.il[127.0.0.1]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
Jun 23 05:14:57 mailserver postfix/smtpd[16306]: warning: mydomain.co.il[127.0.0.1]: SASL CRAM-MD5 authentication failed: authentication failure
Jun 23 05:14:57 mailserver postfix/smtpd[16306]: disconnect from mydomain.co.il[127.0.0.1] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=4/5
Jun 23 05:14:57 mailserver dovecot: imap(shavit): Logged out in=11 out=401
Jun 23 05:14:57 mailserver dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<shavit>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=16310, TLS, session=<BsR2dek16MwlOzfP>
Jun 23 05:14:57 mailserver dovecot: imap(shavit): Logged out in=90 out=884
```

My SSL certificate is valid; I'm using it with `nginx` for 5 virtual hosts under the same domain and they all work, so this option could be eliminated.

What am I doing wrong, or; how would I fix it? Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS configuration is likely a red-herring. `SASL CRAM-MD5` is atypical. Perhaps you want `SASL PLAIN` or `SASL LOGIN`. Since you are using dovecot for IMAP you may want to use dovecot's sasl provider for postfix as well. http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_dovecot

Comment: Actually I just checked my `10-auth.conf` file and `auth_mechanisms` is set to `plain login` already, what could happen so my configuration doesn't take effect?

Comment: Actually I just had to follow the rest of this page, thank you very much!